# TrackPopupMenu equivalent in OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Windows has this nifty little API to create & display a popup menu on the desktop even from a background hidden application. Is there something similar in Mac?

I've a background process started by launcher (in user context) and would like to display a popup menu, with a few options for user to select, when it receives a command from the network. Possible?

The background process itself is a plain C++ command line program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu/1518212-popupmenupositioningitem?language=objc).

The documentation says:

> If view is nil, the location is interpreted in the screen coordinate system. This allows you to pop up a menu disconnected from any window.

So, for example:

```
[myMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:[NSEvent mouseLocation] inView:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion set me off in the right path and I managed to write a sample program to create a menu and display it on the desktop. However, I had to create a view (which required a host window) and pass it as inView: argument to trap item selection (OnMenuSelection method of the view). My challenge now is to make the whole code work from a worker thread :)

Comment: Apparently, getting it work from a background thread is probably not possible if my research so far is right. It seems Cocoa UI stuff is to be handled from the main thread of the app. So I have to figure out a way to handle it from the main thread (some form of signalling from the worker thread).

Comment: The canonical way to do that on Cocoa is to use [dispatch_a/sync](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async), passing the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`)

Comment: Thanks, for throwing the little treats/teasers to the dog ! :-)

Comment: That worked perfectly! It seems the dispatch*() API marshalls the code block to the specified thread and executes it there. It's a no brainer, but still have to be highlighted -- that the onus is on the programmer to manage the lifetime of the referred objects in the marshalled code block and that locals (from outside the code block) are to be avoided. Anyway, nifty stuff!

Answer (score 0):

For the record here's the code that I wrote that displays the menu on the desktop (I'm not a Mac programmer, so there could be errors or my implementation need not be the most optimal):

```
// Dummy View class used to receive Menu Events
@interface DummyView : NSView
{
    NSMenuItem* nsMenuItem;
}
- (void) OnMenuSelection:(id)sender;
- (NSMenuItem*)MenuItem;
@end

@implementation DummyView
- (NSMenuItem*)MenuItem
{
    return nsMenuItem;
}

- (void)OnMenuSelection:(id)sender
{
    nsMenuItem = sender;
}
@end

static void HandleRButtonDown()
{
@autoreleasepool {
    NSRect    graphicsRect;  // contains an origin, width, height
    graphicsRect = NSMakeRect(200, 200, 50, 100);


    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        // Style flags:
    NSUInteger windowStyle = NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable;

    // Window bounds (x, y, width, height).
    NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    NSWindow * window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect
                                          styleMask:windowStyle
                                          backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                          defer:NO];

    // Window controller:
    NSWindowController * windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:window];

    DummyView *nsView = [[DummyView alloc] initWithFrame:graphicsRect];
    [window setContentView:nsView];

    // Create Menu and Dummy View
    NSMenu *nsMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];
    [nsMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];

    NSMenuItem* item1 = [nsMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Menu Item #1" action:@selector(OnMenuSelection:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    [item1 setTag:100];
    [item1 setTarget:nsView];
    [item1 setEnabled:YES];

    NSMenuItem *item2 = [nsMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Menu Item #2" action:@selector(OnMenuSelection:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    [item2 setTag:200];
    [item2 setTarget:nsView];
    [item2 setEnabled:YES];

    [nsMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:item1 atLocation:[NSEvent mouseLocation] inView:nsView];

    printf("Selected item: %d\n", (int)[[nsView MenuItem] tag]);
}

}
```

Call HandleRButtonDown() from main and you should get a popup menu on the screen.

Hope this helps someone.